# I want the program to terminate after 3 incorrect guesses

Tags: c#

I'm making a game that gives user 3 guesses and if the user guesses the right number then they will win a car. I also want the user to only have 3 attempts.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double numberToGuess = 3595.96;
    double userGuess = 0;

    while (userGuess != numberToGuess)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter your price guess: ");
        userGuess = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine()); 

        if (userGuess > numberToGuess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("£{0} is too high!", userGuess);
        }
        else if (userGuess < numberToGuess)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("£{0} is too low!", userGuess);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("£{0} is right! Congratulations.", userGuess);

        }
    } Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Use *decimal* for exact decimal quantities, particularly money. Use double for physical quantities like speed or height. Decimal literals end in the letter m, eg `123.45m`. (That was chosen to remind you that m is for money.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I love school assignments :)*

You should create a new variable like  `int attempts = 0` and increase it at the end of the while loop.

If the attempts greater than 2 you should `break` the loop.

example:

```
int attempts = 0;

while (userGuess != numberToGuess)
{
```

---

```
    }
    attempts++;
    if (attempts > 2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Too bad, you didn't make it within three guesses.");
        break;
    }

} Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, you need a counter to measure how many attempts they've made.  What should the type and name of that counter be?  The initial value?

Then you need logic that tests that counter against the value 3.
You know how to do that test, right?

And when the test indicates the user has reached 3 guesses, it should exit.
You know how to exit, right?

So whats the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
int guessCount = 0;

do
{
    // guess logic
    ...
    else
    {
        // guess is correct
        break;
    }
}while( ++guessCount < 3 )
```